# How to view two small balls bumping into each other as passing through each other(2016 Pascal Contest Q24)?

Tags: logic, mathematical-physics

Here is a question from 2016 Pascal contest(Waterloo, Canada). The question and its full solution are accessible via https://www.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/contests/past_contests.html

Please find below screenshots for quick references.

[image]

[image]

I couldn't understand the following two parts and look for some help:

1. How to view two small balls bumping into each other as passing through each other?
2. How does the configuration provided in the solution preserve the orginal motions and work out so well?

Thank you!

Comment: R1. Because these rubber balls undergo perfectly elastic collisions. 
They just exchange their velocities after the elastic collision, because they are all of the same kind and mass; it's like they just "pass through each other". 
See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision#One-dimensional_Newtonian

Comment: Imagine each ball has an identifying label on them. Now imagine there is a little demon who, the instant two balls bounce off each other, swaps the labels on the balls. Since we are treating the balls as points, we consider that at the instant they collide, their centers are at the exact same point. At that instant, how can we distinguish one from the other? The answer is that we can't!

Comment: @koy, I understand the part where they exchange their velocities after the elastic collision. I feel I still lacked the understanding of taking the viewpoint of treating the balls passing through each other. The configuration in the solution just makes seemingly disorganized motions into an ordered easily analyzable pattern, which is quite amazing :)

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC, if we view the balls as really really tiny, instead of treating them as points, can we treat them with no mass? So, maybe in this way, we take the view that they can pass through each other?

Comment: Well, either way we have an unrealistic idealized approximation - the centers have to be at the identical position at one instant, and for me "very tiny with zero mass" doesn't make that seem any more realistic. But if it makes sense to you, sure.

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the question, when two balls collide they both swap directions but keep moving at the same speed. So in other words, a moment before the collision you have one ball going $1\ ms^{-1}$ to the right and one ball going $1\ ms^{-1}$ to the left. Then a moment after the collision you have one ball going $1\ ms^{-1}$ to the left and one ball going $1\ ms^{-1}$ to the right - so if you can't tell which ball is which then nothing has changed.

Comment: Hmmm... I still get stuck here.  In configuration A of the solution(viewing the balls passing through each other), it takes ball #1 50 seconds to fall out of the tube from the right. If we view the balls reversing their directions after bumping into each other, it takes ball #1 20 seconds to fall out of the tube from the left; it's actually ball #4 that takes 50 seconds but falls out from the left. The labeling doesn't matter, but why does the viewpoint of two balls passing through each other simplify the analysis and provide correct answers? What kinds of information lost are not important?

Comment: The analysis is simplified because instead of tracking a lot of bouncing back and forth you can just measure the distance to the end to find when a ball will fall out. The information lost is the knowledge of exactly _which_ ball will fall out, and it's unimportant because we don't care which balls fall out, only the times at which _some_ ball falls out.